SD-JWT. Verify Error: Invalid JWT Signature
I am new to SD-JWTs, so I just wanted to see how it works.
I am currently trying to implement a JS version of sd-jwt-js. Just a basic thing: issue-validate-present-verify
In local environment, everything works fine (at least it seems this way). Some logs:
Encoded SD-JWT: eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6IjEyMzQiLCJfc2QiOlsiSFJKZDVjVEo1TGlLbWRMTC1HWURDeUdsWkNqQT
hyZUVhOFRxR2w1WHBxVSIsImZUa1E1RmRieE83d2l4bWR2aVl0M1dwcVd0TXJjbWFEQTFNLWhfNTVEd2ciLCJnY
050TTd2eWNra29kODNxV2o4VERYVE9FOGF5aTFUVE1rR3VIemFCVXUwIl0sIl9zZF9hbGciOiJTSEEtMjU2In0.
HzJ9o6hP1iAC676EwKcsI7HieSxHKTPrNxe6k7YeUz3McejLuIToDgLjF79JBAUB7_y4C7i5SeaFO7un_7JDSQ~
WyI1ZmI1ZDJiYzg1YTFlMzc0IiwiZmlyc3RuYW1lIiwiSm9obiJd~WyI4MmVkYjUyZTUxNjYwNWU2IiwibGFzdG
5hbWUiLCJEb2UiXQ~WyI4ZTIxNzc3Y2MwMjhlZDE5Iiwic3NuIiwiMTIzLTQ1LTY3ODkiXQ~

Valid? SD-JWT: {
  payload: {
    id: '1234',
    ssn: '123-45-6789',
    firstname: 'John',
    lastname: 'Doe'
  },
  header: { alg: 'ES256' }
}
.
.
.
Verification Result: {
  payload: { id: '1234', ssn: '123-45-6789', firstname: 'John' },
  header: { alg: 'ES256' }
}

But when I tried to paste the same token to sdjwt.co, I receive "Verify Error: Invalid JWT Signature". Moreover, I've noticed, that even though I have a couple of fields disclosed, I am missing a "typ": "sd+jwt" in header.
I tried to understand the issue myself, but I really don't get it.
Source code:
// test_sdjwt.js
import { SDJwtInstance } from '@sd-jwt/core';
import { ES256, digest, generateSalt } from '@sd-jwt/crypto-nodejs';
import fs from 'fs';

// Function to load JWK from file
const loadJwk = (filePath) => {
  const jwkData = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf-8');
  return JSON.parse(jwkData);
};

(async () => {
    console.log('Debugging starts...');
    
    // Load the persisted key pair
    const privateJwk = loadJwk('privateKey.json');
    const publicJwk = loadJwk('publicKey.json');
    
    // Get signer and verifier using the persisted keys
    const signer = await ES256.getSigner(privateJwk);
    const verifier = await ES256.getVerifier(publicJwk);
    
    // Create SDJwt instance for signing and verifying
    const sdjwt = new SDJwtInstance({
        signer,
        verifier,
        signAlg: ES256.alg,
        hasher: digest,
        hashAlg: 'SHA-256',
        saltGenerator: generateSalt,
    });

    // Define the claims object with the user's information
    const claims = {
        firstname: 'John',
        lastname: 'Doe',
        ssn: '123-45-6789',
        id: '1234',
    };

    const disclosureFrame = {
        _sd: ['firstname', 'lastname', 'ssn'],
    };

    // Issue the SD-JWT
    const credential = await sdjwt.issue(claims, disclosureFrame);
    console.log('Encoded SD-JWT:', credential);

    // Validate the SD-JWT
    const isValid = await sdjwt.validate(credential);
    console.log('Valid? SD-JWT:', isValid);

    if (isValid) {
        // Decode the SD-JWT
        const sdJwtToken = await sdjwt.decode(credential);
        console.log('Decoded Token:', JSON.stringify(sdJwtToken, null, 2));

        const keys = await sdJwtToken.keys(digest);
        console.log({ keys });

        const payloads = await sdJwtToken.getClaims(digest);

        const presentableKeys = await sdJwtToken.presentableKeys(digest);

        console.log({
            payloads: JSON.stringify(payloads, null, 2),
            disclosures: JSON.stringify(sdJwtToken.disclosures, null, 2),
            claim: JSON.stringify(sdJwtToken.jwt?.payload, null, 2),
            presentableKeys,
        });

        // Present the SD-JWT
        const presentationFrame = { firstname: true, id: true, ssn: true };
        const presentation = await sdjwt.present(credential, presentationFrame);
        console.log('Presented SD-JWT:', presentation);

        // Verify the presented SD-JWT
        const requiredClaims = ['firstname', 'ssn', 'id'];
        const verified = await sdjwt.verify(presentation, requiredClaims);
        console.log('Verification Result:', verified);
    } else {
        console.error('Invalid SD-JWT. Cannot proceed with decoding.');
    }
})();

Thanx in advance for your help!
